# Clear all rows from Slickgrid when closing modal window

Tags: slickgrid

I have 2 SlickGrids in a jquery modal layer.
I need to be able to clear all rows when modal layer is closed so that the grids are empty when/if the user reopens the modal layer later.
Actually I can do this with using:

```
dataViewMG1.beginUpdate();
dataViewMG1.getItems().length=0;
dataViewMG1.endUpdate();
```

but if I do this, I cannot repopulate the grids using any of my standard methods:

```
dataViewMG1.beginUpdate();
dataViewMG1.setItems(modaldata1);
dataViewMG1.endUpdate();
invmodalgrid1.invalidate();
invmodalgrid1.render();
```

Anyone have any ideas??
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally empty out my grid before refreshing the data, so it doesn't confuse the user thinking it's the actual refreshed data. That seems to be what you want to do here.

My grid in HTML being:
`<div id="myGrid1" style="width:100%;height:680px;"></div>`

and in my JavaScript, I empty out the grid before refreshing it
`$('#myGrid1').empty(); // empty out the Grid before refreshing the data`

Comment: Hmm... that didn't work for me. There doesn't seem to be an empty() method.  I'm using V2.0.2 SlickGrid.

Comment: Actually... the debugger does run through an empty() method but it doesn't empty anything.  The Grid still shows up populated when reopening.

Comment: The empty is from jQuery as you can see the $ in the front, the method in jQuery is this [link]http://api.jquery.com/empty/[link] If you can't use the jQuery method, you can probably just do a direct javascript call of `document.getElementById("myGrid1").innerHTML = "";`  Replace the `myGrid1` by the name of your Grid

Comment: which by the way in your example is NOT `invmodalgrid1` but is the HTML name you have as in this example here `grid1 = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid1", dataView1, columns1, options1);`, you can see in my example the HTML name is `myGrid1` and NOT `grid1`... remember to use the good one!

Comment: Ah... perfect!  My grid names are subtely different invmodalgrid1 vs invmodalGrid1.  Thanks